# plotting multiple curves out of one numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot several curves out of one numpy array with one plotting object.
The array has a form like:

```
position=np.array([[x11,x12,...,x1n],[y11,...,y1n],[x21,...,x2n],[y21,...],...])
```

It should do someting like the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

position=np.load("position.npy")

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal',autoscale_on=False)
p,=ax.plot(position[0],position[1],'y-',position[2],position[3],'y-',...)
```

but I need the last line to have a from like this:

```
p,=ax.plot(position)
```

I can't write down every position[i] in the plot command. Is there any way to do this, e.g. with a certain array shape or any additional arguments for the plot object?
I need this to plot several trajectories in an animation where (xni,yni) would be the nth particle at time i.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can unpack the list into a series of arguments.  If the 'y-' isn't that important to you, this will work.

```
p, = ax.plot(*position)
```

if you want to add modifiers that apply to all the elements in your list use keyword arguments

```
p, = ax.plot(*position, linestyle = 'dashed', color = 'yellow')
```

Answer (score 3):

The docs for [matplotlib.pyplot.plot(*args, **kwargs)](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) say `If x and/or y is 2-dimensional, then the corresponding columns will be plotted` so you can slice the x and y values out of the `position` array:

```
x = position[::2,:].T 
y = position[1::2,:].T
p,=ax.plot(x, y,'y-')
```

Comment: Thanks @Hammer it does need a transpose.  I've edited my answer.